# Find distance between points and borders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I'd like to ask for your help for the following problem.  I would like to find the distance for each points from the nearest border, represented by the polyline feature here.

I was thinking about using the Near Tool but when I use the latter with the unique polyline of borders as input feature and the points as nearest feature, I get an error 999999.

[image]

Comment: That would be the tool of choice, so there is something odd about your data, are they in the same coordinate system?

Comment: First time I've ever heard of the Near tool.  I've always accomplished this using a spatial join with the option to add a distance field to the nearest feature. Very cool, I'll keep that in mind.